# PageViewController returns false in didFinishAnimating delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

If I scroll the page view controller **SLOWLY** and bring another view controller at its place, in didFinishAnimating delegate method, the completed returns false. What's causing the problem?

It is happening only if I scroll slowly and it works fine if I just swipe to another controller.